# How to copy the contents of an attribute from one vector layer to another one that touches it or intersects it?

Tags: qgis, intersection, fields-attributes, copy

I have 2 layers that intersect, called layer A and layer B.

Layer A has an attribute (X) that I want to copy wholesale (for the whole layer) to layer B, so that when object A1 intersects object B1, attribute X1 from A1 is copied to B1.

I am trying to do this in QGIS.  I used to do this in Mapinfo with an UPDATE query... then I switched to Mac.  I am new to QGIS.

Comment: Maybe a combination of doing a spatial join (Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location) and then using the Field calculator on the output layer of the join could help you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Join attributes by location` from `Processing Toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector General tools -> Join attributes by location` which allows you to copy the attribute of one of the two layers into the other using various `Geometric Predicates` including `intersects` and `touches` as you can see below:

[image]

If you want to transfer all records, even if they is no spatial connection, you need to choose `Keep all records`, otherwise you need to choose `Only keep matching records` located under Joined Table.